# Notification Delegates are not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

My project is developed in Xcode 11 which only consist App delegate(not scene delegate), currently i am using Xcode 13 now but when notification is coming and i am clicking on that the delegates are not getting called.

[image]

Comment: Did you set AppDelegate as the notification delegate? Where?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please copy/paste the code. And also mention what have you done to configure/setup your notification handling

Answer (score 0):

So many gaps in your question. Let's begin.

1. You may have done this already but you first need to setup your capabilities and entitlements properly, which I assume you have.
2. Then, in appDidFinishLaunching delegate method you need to register for push notifications:

   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
   .requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { [weak self] granted, _ in
   print("Permission granted: (granted)")
   guard granted else { return }

   ```
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
                print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
                guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
        }
   ```
3. Then you will receive one of the delegate calls depending if it succeeded or failed:

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
   // Need to send your token to backend
   }

   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
   print(error.localizedDescription)
   }
4. Then, you should look at these delegate methods when receiving a push notification:

For silent pushes:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    
}
```

For non-silent:
(if app is in foreground)

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.banner, .badge, .sound])
}
```

(if app is in background)

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    completionHandler()
}
```

5. If still not working, go to step 0.